# How to write this SQL Order By Clause

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Query which I am trying to write and am now a bit stuck on how to write the order by clause.

Basically the table I am selecting from has items with a severity value. I want to select these items and order them so that the Severity column is ordered Severity 1-4 then 0 and the log date is descending for each.

Severity 1 is highest 4 is lowest and 0 respresents an unassigned severity, I need to display these items Highest severity, oldest item first,  lowest severity, newest item last.

My query so far:

```
SELECT 
        [TicketID],
        [type],
        [Product],
        [Description],
        [LoggedBy],
        [LogDate],
        [Department],
        [AssignedTo],
        [Severity],
        [Status],
        [LastUpdatedBy],
        [LastUpdatedDate]
    FROM 
        SupportTicketsTbl 
    WHERE 
        TicketID NOT IN
        (
            SELECT 
                tck.ticketID  
            FROM 
                SupportTicketsTbl tck
            JOIN
                tblTicketsInEvents tie
            ON
                tck.TicketID = tie.ticketID 
            JOIN
                tblSupportEvent ev
            ON
                tie.eventID = ev.id 
            where 
                ev.type = 1
        )
    AND
        Status <> 'Complete'
```

I guess the easiest way is to create a table variable and select all the Items that are not 0 into it in the order I want, then select all the 0 items into my table variable, and finally just select everything back out of the table variable, but this seems a bit messy so im wondering if there is a more elegant solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't like the UNION answer, and I'm not sure if UNION is guaranteed to preserve order...

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN severity = 0 THEN 999 ELSE Severity END, date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can order by a case statement like this:

```
ORDER BY CASE Severity WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, Severity
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Select all of the ones with severity levels 1-4 using a standard orderby clause, then union the results with a second query that selects only the ones with severity level 0.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I thought id have to do, I was just hoping there would be a way to do this in one ORDER BY etc instead of having to use UNION

Comment: This will not work. the order by will order the entire result.

Comment: ORDER BY needs to be in parenthesis with the individual queries of the UNION and this will usually work. (Not sure if will always work though...)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm very much mistaken, it's something like this:

```
ORDER BY severity DESC, date DESC
```

Insert that line into your SQL.

This will sort the data by Severity first, and if they have the same severity, then sort it according to date.

Comment: That would work winter but I have to have 0 after 4  so it is ordered severity 1,2,3,4,0.